# ActionScript 3: Rotating column label

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

I want to rotate 45 degrees the column label of a table.
How can I do this with Actionscript or Flex?

Comment: [grad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grad_(angle)) or [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle))? (45 grad is a funny angle, but 45 degrees makes a lot of sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Using MXML, you could do it like this: create a custom renderer for the GridColumn components and rotate the label component 45 degrees.

Since you said you're using a table, it probably means you have a DataGrid object, which in turn has columns. Each column is defined by a GridColumn component, with a **headerRenderer** property. Create a copy of the default column header renderer, apply a rotation to the label, using the **rotation** property, and apply this new skin to the column header components.

Hope this helps.

Here is an example of a rotated column header:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="name"
      headerText="Name"
      resizable="false">
    <s:headerRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer rotation="45" />
        </fx:Component>
    </s:headerRenderer>
</s:GridColumn>
```

Have a great day.

Comment: can you please give me an example.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer so you can have an example of a rotated column header.

Answer (score 0):

By the column label I think you mean the table header.

1. Create custom header renderer for your table with text inside
2. On the text property apply the rotate = "45" property (or -45) depending on your case.
3. Very important: USE Embedded font in order to see a rotated text, else you see nothing.

Comment: btw. there is no such thing as Actionscript4. The latest version is 3.0

Comment: Use embed fonts - very good point! I forgot to mention to this little detail.